# An error occured while running app in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

The code:

```
/**
* Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY
*/
package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

public final class BuildConfig {
public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
public static final String APPLICATION_ID =    "com.example.android.sunshine.app";
public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
public static final String FLAVOR = "";
public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
// Fields from build type: debug
public static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY =  4ae9a193e3ce7970984625be19352fd6;
}
```

I think the error may occurred  in line

```
public static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY =  4ae9a193e3ce7970984625be19352fd6;
```

It must be

```
public static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY =  "4ae9a193e3ce7970984625be19352fd6";
```

But when I changed the code and run, the Android Studio automatically change into the code before.

Comment: This file is generated automatically. Show your build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `build.gradle` as:

```
 buildTypes.each {
     it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', "\"4ae9a193e3ce7970984625be19352fd6\""
 }
```

Comment: Cảm ơn. Nó chạy rồi :))))))